# umlauts converted to strange characters

Tags: symbols, characters

I am having trouble with TeXShop version 4.62 macOS BigSur. I am quite new to LaTeX and am modifying a .tex file from a colleague.

Deleting the .pdf and using 'typset' 'LaTeX' of the .tex file works without trouble.

However, changing any part of the text in the .tex file
for example, changing
\author{John Wayne}
to
\author{J Wayne}

destroys all the Umlaut characters (ö, ä and ü) to strange characters. For example, ü becomes a capital A with a tilde on top followed by 1/4.

Perhaps this is a problem with Unicode? Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated.
Thanks and kind regards

Comment: Do you load inputenc somewhere in your file?

Comment: This happens when your document is saved as UTF-8 (good) but interpreted as ISO-8859-1 aka Latin-1 (bad).

Comment: I do, with \usepackage{ansinew}{inputenc}

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, thanks Ingmar (any suggestions how I could have it interpreted as UTF-8?

Comment: Remove \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} and try again.

Comment: Thanks again Urike, that did it!